# NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, nodelist

Do you see any problems with the following:

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
```

Normally `forEach` is just a property of arrays, but by setting it as a property of all `NodeList`s as well, there's no need to convert a `NodeList` to an array before you can loop through its nodes with `forEach`.

Comment: I liked this idea.. Waiting if others point out any problems in it.

Comment: Check out [NodeList.js](https://github.com/eorroe/NodeList.js)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's often not a good idea to extend the functionality of DOM through prototypes, especially in older versions of IE ([article](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)).

However, you can simply use `Array.prototype.forEach` even without adding it to the prototype chain or converting your `NodeList` into an array:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".some.query");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, function(el){ /* ... */ });

/* or */
var forEach = function(ctn, callback){
    return Array.prototype.forEach.call(ctn, callback);
}
forEach(list, function(el){ /* ... */ });
```

See also MDN: [Why can't I use `forEach` or `map` on a `NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList#Why_can%27t_I_use_forEach_or_map_on_a_NodeList.3F).

Comment: there are so many features of JS that would work perfectly well, if it weren't for older versions of IE...

Comment: why did you use `Array.prototype.forEach.call(`... instead of just `Array.prototype.forEach(...` when in syntax at MDN it says you can define `this` in 2nd parameter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach  I'm just trying to improve my understanding.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: Please don't ask questions in comments. If I wasn't active on StackOverflow anymore, you would never get an answer. That being said, `thisArg` is the value of `this` during `callback`, __not__ during `Array.prototype.forEach`.

Comment: Question asked, thanks for time... if you want to explain more please do.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801934/what-is-a-difference-between-array-prototype-foreach-call-vs-array-prototype-for

Comment: Unfortunately this approach didn't work for me for nodes of the XML document, i.e. retrieved via `XMLHttpRequest` or using jQuery `$.get("/test.xml", function(xmlDocument) { Array.prototype.forEach.call(xmlDocument.childNodes, function(node) {...}); });`. However solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24775765/267197) works fine: `Array.from(xmlDocument.childNodes).forEach(function(node) {...});`. For nodes of the DOM document it works fine: `NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach; document.childNodes.forEach(function(node) { ... });`. FF v45, Chrome v53.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working on a library that will be used by other people then it's not a good idea to do this.

If it's just your own code (i.e.. a website) then I guess it's no big deal. You should probably guard it though because in the future browsers will support `NodeList.prototype.forEach` natively (Chrome does already).

```
if (!NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
  NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Zeta mentioned, it would be better to use a convenience function. This version, however, will allow you to give it context.

```
var forEach = function(list, callback, context){
  return Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, callback, context);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`NodeList.prototype.forEach()` is now available in most browsers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Browser compatibility table:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility