# Loop through childNodes

Tags: javascript, loops, children

I'm trying to loop through childNodes like this:

```
var children = element.childNodes;
children.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item);
});
```

However, it output `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` due to `forEach` function. I also try to use `children` instead of `childNodes` but nothing changed.

Does anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

The variable `children` is a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) instance and `NodeList`s are not true [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and therefore they do not inherit the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

Every major browser supports [`nodeList.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

---

**ES5**

You can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) from `Array` to convert the `NodeList` into a proper `Array`.

`var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(children);`

You could also simply use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to invoke `forEach` and pass it the `NodeList` as context.

`[].forEach.call(children, function(child) {});`

---

**ES6**

You can use the [`from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method to convert your `NodeList` into an `Array`.

`var array = Array.from(children);`

Or you can also use the [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) like so

`let array = [ ...children ];`

---

A hack that can be used is `NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach` and you can then use `forEach` with any `NodeList` without having to convert them each time.

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach
var children = element.childNodes;
children.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item);
});
```

---

See [A comprehensive dive into NodeLists, Arrays, converting NodeLists and understanding the DOM](http://toddmotto.com/a-comprehensive-dive-into-nodelists-arrays-converting-nodelists-and-understanding-the-dom/) for a good explanation and other ways to do it.

Comment: How could I convert NodeList to pure array?

Comment: Updated with example but read the link I posted it explains it all :)

Comment: Alternatively, you can do this: `[].forEach.call(element.childNodes, child => console.log(child))`

Comment: Even cooler es6 way: `let items = [ ...children ]` will turn it into an array

Comment: There is a major gotcha with applying Array methods to NodeLists: NodeLists such as node.childNodes are live lists, and if you manipulate the DOM during your loop the NodeList is subject to change, meaning the callback to forEach() my not get called on every element of the list - or more elements than were originally in the list - leading to unpredictable results. It is preferable to turn a NodeList into an array before looping over it.

Comment: Also works:  
for (let i=0; i < obj.childNodes.length; i++) {  
   const childNode = obj.childNodes[i];  
}

Comment: [NodeList.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#browser_compatibility) is now supported in every major browser (I've suggested an edit).

Answer (score 42):

I'm very late to the party, but since `element.lastChild.nextSibling === null`, the following seems like the most straightforward option to me:

```
for(var child=element.firstChild; child!==null; child=child.nextSibling) {
    console.log(child);
}
```

Comment: The most straightforward option is to use regular "for" loop. But your option is interesting.

Comment: I like this the best, was planning to implement the same.. logical and not needing conversions

Answer (score 30):

Here is how you can do it with `for-in` loop.

```
var children = element.childNodes;

for(var child in children){
    console.log(children[child]);
}
```

Comment: You forgot about check:

    if (children.hasOwnProperty(child)) {
      //code here
    }

or you will iterate over unwanted props like "length" and etc.!

Comment: Even better: use `for ... of ...`, it's ES6 syntax though.

Answer (score 7):

```
const results = Array.from(myNodeList.values()).map(parser_item);
```

[NodeList is not Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)
but NodeList.values() return a Array Iterator, so can convert it to Array.

Answer (score 5):

Couldn't resist to add another method, using `childElementCount`. It returns the number of child element nodes from a given parent, so you can loop over it.

```
for(var i=0, len = parent.childElementCount ; i < len; ++i){
    ... do something with parent.children[i]
    }
```

Comment: Beware, `parent.childElementCount != parent.childNodes.length`. `childElementCount` returns the number of `Element` nodes and does not include text and comment nodes, etc. See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_childelementcount.asp

Comment: @Mark As it says in the answer: _"returns the number of child_ **element** _nodes_". But it's good emphasizing it.

Comment: No worries. Technically your answer is correct, it is talking about *element* count and *children*, but I just wanted to add the heads-up, since the initial question was about *nodes*. Too many ways to shoot yourself in the foot :)

Answer (score 4):

Try with `for` loop. It gives error in `forEach` because it is a collection of nodes `nodelist`.

Or this should convert node-list to array

```
function toArray(obj) {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { 
    array[i] = obj[i];
  }
return array;
}
```

Or you can use this

```
var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a functional ES6 way of iterating over a `NodeList`. This method uses the `Array`'s `forEach` like so:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(element.childNodes, f)
```

Where `f` is the iterator function that receives a child nodes as it's first parameter and the index as the second.

If you need to iterate over NodeLists more than once you could create a small functional utility method out of this:

```
const forEach = f => x => Array.prototype.forEach.call(x, f);

// For example, to log all child nodes
forEach((item) => { console.log(item); })(element.childNodes)

// The functional forEach is handy as you can easily created curried functions
const logChildren = forEach((childNode) => { console.log(childNode); })
logChildren(elementA.childNodes)
logChildren(elementB.childNodes)
```

*(You can do the same trick for `map()` and other Array functions.)*

Answer (score 3):

Try this [reverse order traversal]:

```
var childs = document.getElementById('parent').childNodes;
var len = childs.length;
if(len --) do {
    console.log('node: ', childs[len]);
} while(len --);
```

OR [in order traversal]

```
var childs = document.getElementById('parent').childNodes;
var len = childs.length, i = -1;
if(++i < len) do {
    console.log('node: ', childs[i]);
} while(++i < len);
```

Comment: Simple for loop is more readable than while loop. Author doesn't ask for the reverse/inverse order traversal.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a lot of this sort of thing then it might be worth defining the function for yourself.

```
if (typeof NodeList.prototype.forEach == "undefined"){
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = function (cb){
        for (var i=0; i < this.length; i++) {
            var node = this[i];
            cb( node, i );
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < e.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var id = e.childNodes[i].id;
    }
```

Comment: There's no need to use `var` anymore, and `for...of` is much cleaner, I think.

Comment: for...of is much cleaner ??? And red is the most beautiful color...  The question is: Loop through childNodes. And my for loop does it very effectively, very C-style..

Comment: I'm not saying it doesn't work. I'm just saying that this style of looping over iterable objects and the usage of `var` for variable declaration in JS is a little dated. Does writing it C-style offer a big advantage?

Answer (score -1):

Just Change `children` to `[...children]` to convert `NodeList` to the array of `Nodes`, so `.forEach` can be worked.

```js
let element = document.querySelector('ul');
var children = element.childNodes;
[...children].forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```