# Reading the HTML Children of a <UL> collection

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm trying to retrieve all the `<li>` **child nodes** of a Parent `<ul>` node via a loop during runtime. However the loop runs forever causing the browser to immediately crash. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<ul id="new-ul">
     <li> <input value="323" /> </li>
     <li> <input value="421" /> </li>
     <li> <input value="547" /> </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
//Attempting to retrieve each value in input fields of each <li> child
var idbox = document.getElementById("new-ul");
while (idbox.firstChild) {
     console.log(idbox.firstChild);
     //Browser crashes here
}
```

Comment: Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775725/loop-through-childnodes

Comment: Well `idbox.firstChild` always has a `firstChild`, so you're creating a endless loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is creating an infinite loop because the condition for the while loop will always evaluate to true. Instead, you wanna do this

```
var parent = document.getElementById('new-ul');
var children = parent.children;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  console.log(children[i]);
  // Do stuff
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fm641poa/)

Answer (score 2):

In jquery use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#new-ul input").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).val())
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve it like this

```
Array.prototype.map.call( document.querySelectorAll("#new-ul input"), function( element,index ){

    console.log( element.value );

});
```

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/4n4dwqpt/

Answer (score -1):

Could be done by jquery $.each easily

```
$("#your-ul-id li").each(function(){ 
    console.log($(this)) 
});
```