# How to store each div span id into dynamic list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I read and store each span id inside of div class `v-h-box` into a separate list and further sort each list.

I want output as `[[2,3,4,5],[1,6,7,8]]`

```js
let x = document.querySelectorAll(".v-h-box");
let y = Array.from(x);
console.log(y);

let answerArray = [];
y.forEach((item, index) => {
    if(item.children.length >= 1){
        answerArray.push(item.children[0].id)
    }
})
```

```html
<div class="v-h-box">
  <span class="v-h-multiple">
    <span id="4" draggable="true"> Tokoyo </span>
    <span id="2" draggable="true"> UK </span>
    <span id="5" draggable="true"> USA </span>
    <span id="3" draggable="true"> New York </span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="v-h-box">
  <span class="v-h-multiple">
    <span id="8" draggable="true"> Paris </span>
    <span id="6" draggable="true"> Mumbai </span>
    <span id="7" draggable="true"> India </span>
    <span id="1" draggable="true"> France </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `<spans>` that you're trying to find are childs of the `v-h-multiple` div, you'll need to go a `children` deeper

I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24775765/5625547) (`[...]`) technique to create an array of the children so we can use `map()` to return only the ids.

Then using [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort them.

I've also added `parseInt` in the `map` to convert the ID's to integers.

```js
let x = document.querySelectorAll(".v-h-box");
let y = Array.from(x);

let answerArray = [];
y.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.children.length >= 1) {
        let childIds = [...item.children[0].children].map((c) => parseInt(c.id));
        answerArray.push(childIds.sort((a, b) => a - b))
    }
})

console.log(answerArray);
```

```html
<div class="v-h-box">
  <span class="v-h-multiple">
    <span id="4" draggable="true"> Tokoyo </span>
    <span id="2" draggable="true"> UK </span>
    <span id="5" draggable="true"> USA </span>
    <span id="3" draggable="true"> New York </span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="v-h-box">
  <span class="v-h-multiple">
    <span id="8" draggable="true"> Paris </span>
    <span id="6" draggable="true"> Mumbai </span>
    <span id="7" draggable="true"> India </span>
    <span id="1" draggable="true"> France </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

```json
[
  [
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
  ],
  [
    1,
    6,
    7,
    8
  ]
]
```

Comment: Using `.sort()` without a comparator is not enough, because it will perform a natural sort instead of a numeric sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to find all div and using `Array.from` and `array#map` you can get all `id` attribute of `span`.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.v-h-box');
const result = Array
  .from(divs)
  .map(div => {
    const spans = div.querySelectorAll('.v-h-multiple span');
    return Array
      .from(spans)
      .map(span => Number(span.getAttribute('id')))
      .sort((a,b) => a - b);
  });
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div class="v-h-box">
  <span class="v-h-multiple">
    <span id="4" draggable="true"> Tokoyo </span>
    <span id="2" draggable="true"> UK </span>
    <span id="5" draggable="true"> USA </span>
    <span id="3" draggable="true"> New York </span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="v-h-box">
  <span class="v-h-multiple">
    <span id="8" draggable="true"> Paris </span>
    <span id="6" draggable="true"> Mumbai </span>
    <span id="7" draggable="true"> India </span>
    <span id="1" draggable="true"> France </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you just need a nested loop, instead of that single `[0]`:

```js
let x = document.querySelectorAll(".v-h-box");
let y = Array.from(x);

let answerArray = [];
y.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (item.children.length >= 1) {
    let xx = item.children[0].children;
    let yy = Array.from(xx);

    let subArray = [];
    yy.forEach(span => subArray.push(parseInt(span.id)));
    answerArray.push(subArray.sort((a, b) => a - b));
  }
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(answerArray));
```

```html
<div class="v-h-box">
  <span class="v-h-multiple">
  <span id="4" draggable="true"> Tokoyo </span>
  <span id="2" draggable="true"> UK </span>
  <span id="5" draggable="true"> USA </span>
  <span id="3" draggable="true"> New York </span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="v-h-box">
  <span class="v-h-multiple">
  <span id="8" draggable="true"> Paris </span>
  <span id="6" draggable="true"> Mumbai </span>
  <span id="7" draggable="true"> India </span>
  <span id="1" draggable="true"> France </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

However, if you are allowed to use `Array.from()`, a relatively new construct in JS, you can presumably also use `for...of`, and a much shorter code:

```js
let answerArray = [];
for (let item of document.querySelectorAll(".v-h-box"))
  if (item.children.length >= 1) {
    let subArray = [];
    for (let span of item.children[0].children)
      subArray.push(parseInt(span.id));
      answerArray.push(subArray.sort((a,b)=>a-b));
  }
console.log(JSON.stringify(answerArray));
```

```html
<div class="v-h-box">
  <span class="v-h-multiple">
  <span id="4" draggable="true"> Tokoyo </span>
  <span id="2" draggable="true"> UK </span>
  <span id="5" draggable="true"> USA </span>
  <span id="3" draggable="true"> New York </span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="v-h-box">
  <span class="v-h-multiple">
  <span id="8" draggable="true"> Paris </span>
  <span id="6" draggable="true"> Mumbai </span>
  <span id="7" draggable="true"> India </span>
  <span id="1" draggable="true"> France </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

And then you can go with map/reduce magics sparing a line here and there (like for creating the arrays):

```js
let answerArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".v-h-box"))
  .reduce((result, item) => {
    if (item.children.length >= 1)
      result.push(Array.from(item.children[0].children)
        .map(span => parseInt(span.id)).sort((a, b) => a - b));
    return result;
  }, []);
console.log(JSON.stringify(answerArray));
```

```html
<div class="v-h-box">
  <span class="v-h-multiple">
  <span id="4" draggable="true"> Tokoyo </span>
  <span id="2" draggable="true"> UK </span>
  <span id="5" draggable="true"> USA </span>
  <span id="3" draggable="true"> New York </span>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="v-h-box">
  <span class="v-h-multiple">
  <span id="8" draggable="true"> Paris </span>
  <span id="6" draggable="true"> Mumbai </span>
  <span id="7" draggable="true"> India </span>
  <span id="1" draggable="true"> France </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Which is shorter, but not necessarily more readable than the previous one.