# What is a difference between Array.prototype.forEach.call vs Array.prototype.forEach

Tags: javascript

According to documentation at MDN you can provide this argument to forEach function if invoked like this, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach, But it doesn't work. It works if i use `call` with it.

As i understand call and apply are used to supply `this` and arguments to function. However, there should be no need. So what am i missing?

Comment: Are you trying to use this with array-like objects? Such as nodelist etc?

Comment: @slebetman: [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15267295/nodelist-prototype-foreach-array-prototype-foreach/15267652#comment40356278_15267652)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

It's already in the [documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) (emphasis mine):

> 15.4.4.18 `Array.prototype.forEach ( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )`
>
> `callbackfn` should be a function that accepts three arguments.
>   `forEach` calls `callbackfn` once for each element present in the
>   array, in ascending order. `callbackfn` is called only for elements of
>   the array which actually exist; it is not called for missing elements
>   of the array.
>
> **If a `thisArg` parameter is provided, it will be used as the `this`
>   value for each invocation of `callbackfn`**. If it is not provided,
>   `undefined` is used instead.

`thisArg` is only used in the invocation of `callbackfn`. It's not, however, used to provide the `this` value for `forEach`, where `this` needs to be an array like structure (that means it has a `length` property). If you use `Array.prototype.forEach(..., someObject)`, the `this` value in `forEach`'s context will be `undefined`.

#### Simplified `forEach` version (which shows the problem immediately)

```
function forEach( callback , thisArg ){
    // The algorithm parses the length as UInt32, see step 3.
    // >>> not only acts as bit shift, but also forces the 
    // value into an unsigned number.

    var len = this.length >>> 0, // using "this", not "thisArg"!
        i;

    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        callback.call(thisArg, this[i]);
        // thisArg   ^^^^^^^^^ is used here, not up at length
    }
}

// example calls:
var logArguments = function(args){
    console.log(args, this);
}
forEach(logArguments, [1,2,3]); // logs nothing
forEach.call([1,2,3], logArguments); // logs 1, 2, 3
forEach.call([1,2,3], logArguments, [2,3,4]); // logs "1 Array [2,3,4]"
                                              //      "2 Array [2,3,4]"
                                              //      "3 Array [2,3,4]"
```

Comment: i wish you would not use `>>>`. Seeing it first time this year. Lots of googling and still in dark. What's the purpose of it here?...

Comment: without answer below i'd have been confused forever, but it got me on right track and yours took me ahead. Thanks both of you.

Comment: If anyone else finds this, `>>>` is zero-fill right shift ([JS operators reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)). In this case it's used as a slightly more compact (but substantially more confusing) way to say `Number(this.length)`, casting `this.length` to a number in case it happens to be a string.

Comment: @ecraig12345: It also forces it to an unsigned integer, whereas `Number` can result in a double precision value. That's a __verbatim__ translation of the original step "Let len be ToUint32(lenValue)."

Answer (score 3):

It definitely does work, the second parameter to `forEach` supplies context to the callback

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4];
var sum = {value: 0};

numbers.forEach(function(num){ 
   this.value += num;
}, sum);

console.log(sum); // Object {value: 10}
```